# how to get multiple min values from two SQL tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, min

I have two tables, a `Members` table and a `Plan` table. They are structured as follows.

```
member   start_date     Mplan               Pplan    version start_dt     end_dt
John     20120701       johnplan           johnplan  1       20120601     20130531
John     20130201       johnplan           johnplan  2       20130601     20140531
John     20130901       johnplan 
John     20131201       johnplan
```

I need to update the `start_date` on the `Members` table to be the minimum value present for that `member` but within the same `Plan` version.

### Example:

`20130201` would be changed to `20120701` and `20131201` would change to `20130901`.

### Code:

```
UPDATE Members
SET start_date =(
    SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM Members a
        LEFT JOIN Plan ON Mplan = Pplan AND
        start_date BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
    WHERE member=a.member
        AND start_date BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
)
```

Unfortunately this sets every single `start_date` to `19900101` aka the lowest value in the entire table for that column.

Comment: You didn't correlate your inner SELECT to your outer UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the minimum start date of each member for a specific plan. The following will provide you that.

```
select MIN(start_date) as min_date,a.member as member_name,a.Mplan as plan_name    FROM Members a inner JOIN [plan] p ON a.Mplan = p.Pplan AND
    start_date BETWEEN p.start_dt AND p.end_dt
    group by a.member, a.Mplan
```

The result will be something like this.

```
min_date                member_name plan_name
2012-07-01 00:00:00.000 John        johnplan1
2013-09-01 00:00:00.000 John        johnplan2
```

Use this to update each member's start date for a plan with the lowest start date of the respective plan.

```
update members 
set start_date= tbl.min_date from
(SELECT MIN(start_date) as min_date,a.member as member_name,a.Mplan as   plan_name FROM Members a
    inner JOIN [plan] p ON a.Mplan = p.Pplan AND
    start_date BETWEEN p.start_dt AND p.end_dt
    group by a.member, a.Mplan) as tbl
where member=tbl.member_name and Mplan=tbl.plan_name
```

I created your 2 tables, members and plan, and tested this solution with sample data and it works. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to convert the dates to Datetime. You will have a greater precision, the possibility to store hours, days and minutes as well as access to date specific functions, international conversion and localization.

If  your column is a Varchar(8), then it uses no less space than a Datetime column.

That said, what you are looking for is row_number().

Something like:

```
SELECT Member, MPlan, Start_Date, Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Member, MPLan ORDER BY Start_Date) as Version
FROM Members
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this ? I didn't test it.

```
With Member_start_dt as
(
    select *, (select start_dt from Pplan where M.start_date <= start_dt AND M.start_date >= end_dt) as Pplan_date
    from Members M
),
Member_by_plan as 
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by Pplan_date order by start_date) num
    from Member_start_dt
)
update M
Set M.start_date = MBP1.start_date
from  Members M
    inner join Member_by_plan MBP1 ON MBP1.member = M.Member AND num = 1  
    inner join Member_by_plan MBP2 ON MBP2.member = M.Member AND MBP2.Pplan_date = MBP1.Pplan_date AND MBP2.start_date = M.start_date
```